# I need to categorize my customer for eligible for bonus and Ineligible based on orders count

Tags: sql, counting, redash

I have 2 tables, the first one is Orders as the following:

| Customer_ID | ORDER_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 11 | completed |
| A | 12 | completed |
| B | 13 | completed |
| B | 14 | completed |
| B | 15 | completed |
| C | 16 | completed |
| B | 17 | cancelled |
| A | 18 | cancelled |

And the second one is Customers as the following:

| Customer_ID | Customer_status | join_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 2022-02-09 |
| b | 15 | 2022-02-10 |
| c | 10 | 2022-02-10 |

I tried a query to use as a sub-query but it didn't work, I'm new to this and still struggling.

```
 SELECT T1.customer_id, count (T1.ORDER_ID) as Orders_count
 FROM orders T1 LEFT join customers T2
 on  T1.Customer_ID = T2.Customer_ID
 where T1.STATUS= 6 AND T2.Customer_status= 15
 AND T2.join_date between timestamp'2022-02-10 'and timestamp '2022-02-11'
 GROUP  BY T1.Customer_ID ORDER  BY T1.Customer_ID
```

I want to categorize the users as eligible or ineligible for a bonus. The eligibles are the ones whose `user_status = 15`, who made more than 1 order, and whose joining date is 2022-02-10, others are ineligible. I want the table to show both, I'm using redash for that matter.

Comment: yes I removed it

Comment: your query doesn't reprsent the data you presented, customer has no status 50 and order has no status at all.

Answer (score 0):

`group by` and `having` can be used to create a list of customers who have placed many orders.

Then  a `left join` to join this list and see who is eligible or not.

```
select c.*, if(s.Customer_ID is not null, 'YES','NO') as Eligible
from customers c 
left join (
  select Customer_ID
  from orders
  group by Customer_ID
  having count(1) > 1
) as s on s.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID and c.Customer_status = 15 and c.join_date = '2022-02-10'
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OWBXMxWm)

Comment: i don't believe, that he has the right rdms tagged, besides without the status, how can you tell which row he actually wants

Comment: According to the description, the eligible ones are the customers with customer_status 15 and join date 2022-02-10 and having more than one order.

Comment: the order status is the relevant status to get the right row, but he hasn't added the data, so your query is only a gues

Comment: the eligible ones are the customers with customer_status 15 and join date 2022-02-10 and having more than one completed order. and  I need the count in a row

Comment: count of what ?